# Room Entity default values VS secondary constructor

Tags: android, kotlin

Is it strictly a matter of preference, or is there a reason to use one method over the other?

**Default values**

```
@Entity
data class Folder(
        @PrimaryKey
        val id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
        val parentId: String?,
        val title: String?,
        val pinned: Boolean = false
)

// usage
Folder(parentId = null, title = "Folder")
```

**Secondary constructor**

```
@Entity
data class Folder(
        @PrimaryKey
        val id: String,
        val parentId: String?,
        val title: String?,
        val pinned: Boolean
) {
    @Ignore
    constructor(parentId: String?, title: String?) : this(
            UUID.randomUUID().toString(), parentId, title, false
    )
}

// usage
Folder(null, "Folder")
```

Forgive me if this is a trivial question, I'm just trying to avoid any hiccups down the road because I haven't shipped an app with Kotlin or Room yet.. and I want to avoid any data related issues once the app goes live.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to write code on the idiomatic Kotlin you must use the solution with "Default values".
Also use "Named Arguments":

```
println(Folder(parentId = 100, title = "anything"))
```

Also, if you want Room to assign automatic IDs to entities, you can set the `@PrimaryKey` `autoGenerate` property.

Comment: I see, so it ultimately does come down to personal preference and there's no effect on the underlying `Room` implementation whether you use one method over the other..